# I got an Error #1009 saying I Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. Now what?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs6

So I got that error when trying to run my game. It's a simple little game that revolves around picking up orbiting jerry cans whilst trying to avoid orbiting enemies. So I hit Ctrl+Shft+Enter and found the problem was at line 26 (if (this.y +...) in my Ship Class.

```
package 
{

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;


    public class Ship extends Sprite
    {

        public function Ship(_x:int,_y:int)
        {
        this.x = _x;
        this.y = _y;
        //adds event listener that allows the player to move
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, player_move);
    }

    public function player_move(e:Event)
    {
        //check if at left or right side of stage
        if (this.y - this.height / 2 <= 0)
        {
            this.y = 50;
        }
        if (this.y + this.height / 2 >= stage.height - this.height)
        {
            this.y = 370;
        }
        if (this.x - this.width / 2 <= 0)
        {
            this.x = 50;
        }
        if (this.x + this.width / 2 >= stage.width - this.width)
        {
            this.x = 500;
        }


    }

    public function left():void
    {
        //the speed in which the player will move left
        this.x -=  10;
    }
    public function right():void
    {
        //the speed in which the player will move right
        this.x +=  10;
    }
    public function up():void
    {
        //the speed in which the player will move right
        this.y -=  10;
    }
    public function down():void
    {
        //the speed in which the player will move right
        this.y +=  10;
    }
  }
}
```

Now what do I do? How do I fix this? I can't find the answer anywhere. I know it has something to do with my Main class as in it, I have stated that if the Player his the enemy, his ship is placed back at his original co-ords.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Has it been added to the stage?  `stage` is probably an invalid reference.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, I'm new to all this. But what exactly do you mean has it been added to the stage? What exactly would I have to do to add it to the stage or make `stage` a valid reference?

Comment: the first line in your player_mve method should be: if(!stage){return;}

Answer (score 1):

Your null object is the `stage` reference. Every DisplayObject has a reference to the stage, however, this is null until the object is actually on the stage.

The stage is the main container of your application. Everything that is visual in your application will be on the stage in some way. Your main document class will be on the stage, all timeline objects, etc.

Your object is counted as being on stage even if its added to a different container, just as long as that container is on the stage in some way. So to put it in the most basic terms, if the object is somewhere where the user should be able to see it, stage will not be null.

To work around this, you're going to have to add your `ENTER_FRAME` event listener after your object has been added to the stage. Luckily, you can listen for an event that is fired when this happens.

In the constructor:

```
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
```

Then add your handler:

```
private function init(evt:Event){
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, player_move);
}
```

Remember, `stage` will be null until an object is added to the stage, which is the event we're listening for now. Then, just add your ship to the main game or whichever container it's going in, `container.addChild(ship)`, and if that container is a part of the stage, you should be good to go.